# simulate 3G n/w using wifi

Tags: android, wifi, 3g

I am working on a Android application which can only run on a 3G network but We currently do not have a 3G network available in the country. Is there any way to hack/modify some parts of Android's connectivity Manager or other framework components to simulate the behavior that we are using 3G n/w but underlying the requests are being processed through Wifi? Has anyone tried anything like this? and If at all it can be done, How can it be acheived?

Answer (score 0):

http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/ This tool may be of help. You would need to look at the source, see how it works and recreate for android.

I don't know of any android apps which do this.

Comment: You might find it simpler to run the dummynet tool on the server side or on a machine bridging wifi to lan rather than the phone side.

Comment: Good idea... This would mitigate the need to refactor for Android.